# React - Is it possible that React will remount unmounted component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component

Is it possible that React will remount the same instance of a component that was unmounted previously?

Do React and React-Native manage this the same way?

Answer (score 0):

No, once a component has been unmounted it will be destroyed. The same instance with the same state will never be used again.

The behaviour is identical for React (web) and React Native.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But is it said somewhere in the documentation? What's the source?

Comment: I haven't read the docs for a long time, but that's the way it works. Feel free to do the research to confirm yourself.

Comment: I haven't found such statement [in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html). That's why I'm asking on Stackverflow.